# Es posible activar una alarma por medio de EditText?

Tags: java, android

yo activo mi alarma por medio de datepicker y timepicker, pero me gustaría saber si es posible activar la alarma por medio de un editText con mm/dd/yyyy ?

Mi código para activarla por el datepicker y timepicker.

```
private void setAlarm(Uri passuri){

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(datePicker.getYear(),
                datePicker.getMonth(),
                datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
                00);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), pruebaintento.dos.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(),
                RQS_1,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Si, lo es. Puedes implementar un _InputFilter_ para el formato y usar un _EditText_ con inputType="phone", luego usar el método _parse(String d)_ de _DateFormat_ para obtener un _Date_.

Comment: @StefanNolde puedes poner una solución más amplia? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente es lo mismo, sólo cambia la forma en la que ingresas la información a Calendar

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(tuEditText.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, respuesta perfecta! Solucionado :)!